# selenium keeps asking me for a service even though i already have have passed it

Tags: python, selenium, heroku, automation, webdriver

I am trying to run my selenium project on heroku but i keep getting this error

```
DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
```

this is error did not show before when i was running the code on computer,
so i searched about and now instead of this:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome( options=options,executable_path=os.environ.get("CHROMEDRIVER_PATH"))
```

im writing this:

```
 driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options,executable_path=os.environ.get("CHROMEDRIVER_PATH"))
```

but i keeps getting the same error does anyone knows why is this?

Answer (score 0):

just remove executable_path and it should work